# How can I push two VC but only presenting top VC

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I would like to emulate contact list in ios. When one taps + button to add contact, a new view controller is presented that gives you textfields to enter contact name and additional info for saving about that contact. Once you tap Done button, the next view controller presented already seems to be embedded in a navigation controller with the button that takes you back to the contact list. I've tried code found on here but it pushes 3 view onto navigation stack

```
 //first attempt
 var controllers = navigationController?.viewControllers
 controllers?.append(secondVc)
 controllers?.append(thirdVC)
 navigationController?.setViewControllers(controllers!, animated: true)

 //second attempt
 let pushVC = UIViewController()
 let backVC = UIViewController()

 if let navigationController = navigationController {
    navigationController.pushViewController(pushVC, animated: true)
    let stackCount = navigationController.viewControllers.count
    let addIndex = stackCount - 1
    navigationController.viewControllers.insert(backVC, atIndex: addIndex)
 }
```

I've also tried other combinations that look cringy. Here is what I want it to look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEraS.jpg

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
navigationController.pushViewController(secondVc, animated:false)
navigationController.pushViewController(thirdVc, animated:true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Apple does the same by presenting a new window, with the form to create a new contact.

After making the new window as the `keyWindow`, they push the contact details VC on to the navigation controller on the original window. This push happens in the background, which the user is not able to witness.

You can view the same by attaching a debugger to the Contacts app.

Heres a screenshot of the view hierarchy. You will be able to see that there are no view controllers from the original window underneath the `CNContactContentViewController`.

[image: Contacts app add contact view heirarchy]

When the user taps Done, the original window is restored as the `keyWindow`, and the contact details VC is updated to show the newly added contact.